# Группировка данных по дате и ключам

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос

Существует проходная. Проходная фиксирует пропуск и записывает в логи запись о проходе в следующую таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE tabel_tabel (
    ID NUMBER,
    DATE_LOG DATE,
    DATE_LOG_TRUNC DATE,
    WORKER_ID NUMBER,
    ACCESS_STATUS NUMBER(1)
);
```

В следующем формате

```
INSERT ALL
  -- первый день, затуп считывания в начале дня
  INTO tabel_tabel (ID, DATE_LOG, DATE_LOG_TRUNC,WORKER_ID,ACCESS_STATUS) 
VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01.09.2023 7:49:55', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('01.09.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 123, 0)
  INTO tabel_tabel (ID, DATE_LOG, DATE_LOG_TRUNC,WORKER_ID,ACCESS_STATUS)
VALUES (2, TO_DATE('01.09.2023 7:50:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('01.09.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 123, 0)
  INTO tabel_tabel (ID, DATE_LOG, DATE_LOG_TRUNC,WORKER_ID,ACCESS_STATUS)
VALUES (3, TO_DATE('01.09.2023 17:01:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('01.09.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY'),  123, 1)

  -- второй день, затуп считывания в конце дня
  INTO tabel_tabel (ID, DATE_LOG, DATE_LOG_TRUNC,WORKER_ID,ACCESS_STATUS)
VALUES (4, TO_DATE('02.09.2023 7:55:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02.09.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 123, 0)
  INTO tabel_tabel (ID, DATE_LOG, DATE_LOG_TRUNC,WORKER_ID,ACCESS_STATUS)
VALUES (5, TO_DATE('02.09.2023 17:00:30', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02.09.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 123, 1)
  INTO tabel_tabel (ID, DATE_LOG, DATE_LOG_TRUNC,WORKER_ID,ACCESS_STATUS)
VALUES (6, TO_DATE('02.09.2023 17:01:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02.09.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY'),  123, 1)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Иногда софт для проходных может тупить и считывать пропуск больше чем один раз.

На реальном примере данных гораздо больше, поэтому выборка происходит по `WORKER_ID` и диапазону дат

```
select t.id,
 TO_CHAR(t.DATE_LOG, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as date_log,
 t.date_log_trunc,
 t.worker_id,
 t.access_status
from tabel_tabel t
where t.date_log_trunc >= TO_DATE('01.09.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  AND t.date_log_trunc <= SYSDATE
  AND t.worker_id = 123
```

Результат запроса выглядит следующим образом

```
ID  DATE_LOG             DATE_LOG_TRUNC  WORKER_ID  ACCESS_STATUS
1   01.09.2023 07:49:55  01-SEP-23       123        0
2   01.09.2023 07:50:00  01-SEP-23       123        0
3   01.09.2023 17:01:00  01-SEP-23       123        1
4   02.09.2023 07:55:00  02-SEP-23       123        0
5   02.09.2023 17:00:30  02-SEP-23       123        1
6   02.09.2023 17:01:00  02-SEP-23       123        1
```

Необходимо привести её к формату, когда на дату по `WORKER_ID` формируется два поля на `ACCESS_STATUS` (0 - вход, 1 - выход) с значением минимальной даты входа и максимальной даты выхода, а то есть

```
DATE_LOG_TRUNC  TIME_IN    TIME_OUT   WORKER_ID
01.09.2023      07:49:55   17:01:00   123
02.09.2023      07:55:00   17:01:00   123
```

[dbfiddle, если необходимо](https://dbfiddle.uk/U8Q9hdD2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот таким образом можно сгруппировать данные по заданным условиям:

```
select 
  t.worker_id,
  t.date_log_trunc,
  to_char(min(case when ACCESS_STATUS = 0 then date_log end), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') inCome,
  to_char(max(case when ACCESS_STATUS = 1 then date_log end), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') outCome
  from tabel_tabel t
group by t.worker_id,
date_log_trunc
order by date_log_trunc
```

Выводит за день по сотруднику минимальную дату входа и максимальную дату выхода